# C# undo file.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, readline

I am reading huge textfile (1.8 GB) with

```
     while ((j = file.ReadLine()) != null) {...}
```

However, after some operations i got myself into situation, when I would like to 'undo' last ReadLine, so the next ReadLine would actually read exactly the same line.

Is there any way to do it? :)

The same job would do 'looking at next character' without any reading, so that I could, based on this character, decide if I want to read next line or not.

example:

```
    >1
    abc
    def
    >2
    ghi
```

After I read 'def' with ReadLine() I want to know if the next line contains '>' character or if there are just letters of alphabet.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For just 'looking at next character', use the Peek() method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks you a lot. I found this, but was confused with int return value (expected char):)) But of course 62 stands for '>'. Thanks again and have a nice day!

Comment: They use int so they can return -1 when there's nothing to read.

Comment: @Perlnika Don't forget to accept it if it was correct for you :)

Comment: I have just accepted:) It all works with checking if file.Peek()==(62)

Comment: You might consider converting '>' from char to int instead of using the value 62 directly. Otherwise someone reading the code has to guess what the number stands for. Thanks for accepting!

Answer (score 3):

For looking at the next character you can use the method [Peek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

This will return the next character without changing your location in the file.

Answer (score 2):

What you actually looking for is a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Instead of trying to look ahead into your next input (that may or may not be present or valid) you should be setting your state to be `current is 'def', check for '>'` and performing necessary operation on the next iteration.